# how to make bold only speciifc text in rdl file

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, rdl

I have an RDL File.

I have one column which displays:

> "This is a Queue Builder Record"

I want to make the word "Queue" bold and all other words remain normal.

e.g.: This is a **Queue** Builder Record"

When I am trying to do this the entire column becomes bold.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using SQL 2005 or SQL 2008?  Is this column coming from the datbase or a static textbox? Also, do you have access to Business Intelligence Development Studio? Or are you working the code itself?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I will assume when you say RDL, you have referring to an SSRS Report file.  If you are running this RDL file in 2005, you cannot do this cleanly, you could split the column into 3 columns and bold the middle column that contains "Queue" but that is messy and ugly.
If you are using 2008 there are a couple ways to do it, the easiest would be to:

1. Click into the text box (so your cursor is in the text box)
2. Right Click and select "CREATE PLACEHOLDER"
3. In Markup Type select "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles"
4. In Value:`="This is a <b>Queue</b> Builder"`

You're ready to go.